# Iff statement with list - Informatica 8.5/9.x

Tags: informatica

It is possible to use a list of words to prepare similar if statement:
IIF(INSTR(LOWER(DESC_),'JAVA' or 'C++' or'ddddd')

at the moment I use:
IIF(INSTR(LOWER(DESC_),'JAVA')OR INSTR(LOWER(DESC_),'C++') OR .....,
Informatica 8.5/9.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the expression you have would not work, because you are converting the port to LOWERCASE and doing INSTR with capital 'JAVA'.

Coming to your question, there is no way to use single INSTR with multiple strings. However you can get the same functionality with REG_MATCH like below:

```
REG_MATCH(LOWER(DESC_), '.*(java|c\+\+|ddddd).*')
```

Note:

- `.*` matches any character
- `(...)` defines a group
- `java|c\+\+|ddddd` strings to search seperated by pipe (|). `+` is part of regular expression syntax. So it needs to be excaped with `\`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do a DECODE(TRUE, condition1, result1, condition2, result2, ... , defaultresultwithnocondition)